# The meaning of $\bigcap_{x\in G} x^{-1}Hx$ and the proof for the fact that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $y^{-1}Ny=N$ for every $y\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, let $N=\bigcap_{x\in G}x^{-1}Hx$. Prove that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $y^{-1}Ny=N$ for every $y\in G$.

What does $N=\bigcap_{x\in G}x^{-1}Hx$ mean? I'm confused and I don't know how to utilize this condition.

Comment: Suppose H={h1,h2,....hn}… then x^-1Hx={x^-1h1x,x^-1h2x,..x^-1hnx}

Comment: It means the intersection of all subgroups of the form $x^{-1}Hx$, as $x$ ranges of the elements of $G$. By definition $x^{-1}Hx=\{\, x^{-1}hx\mid h\in H\,\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As none of the other answers actually tell you what $\bigcap_{x\in G}x^{1}Hx$ means, I thought I should tell you. You can then use their answers if you wish to solve the problem.

> So, $\bigcap_{x\in G}x^{-1}Hx$ is the intersection of all subgroups of the form $x^{-1}Hx$. That is all it means.

For example, if $G=S_3$ and $H=\{1, (12)\}$ then you cycle through each $x\in S_3$ and form $x^{-1}Hx$. You then intersect these sets. So,
$$\begin{align*}
1^{-1}H1&=H\\
(12)^{-1}H(12)&=H\\
(13)^{-1}H(13)&=\{1, (23)\}\\
(23)^{-1}H(23)&=\{1, (13)\}\\
(123)^{-1}H(123)&=\{1, (23)\}\\
(132)^{-1}H(132)&=\{1, (13)\}
\end{align*}$$
Their intersection is the set $\{1\}$, as $1$ is the only element in each of these sets, so $\bigcap_{x\in G}x^{-1}Hx=\{1\}$.

**Exercise:** If I had chosen the subgroup $K=\{1, (123), (132)\}\leq S_3$ then $\bigcap_{x\in G}x^{-1}Kx=K$. Prove this, and understand why.

Comment: As the concept is well explained, however, I didn't find these two expressions for $\bigcap_{x\in G}x^{-1}Hx$ equivalent. For example,if choose $h=(12)$, $x=1$, then we get $x^{-1}Hx=(12)$. So according to the second or "alternative description",$(12)$ is in the set $\bigcap_{x\in G}x^{-1}Hx$. However, accoring to the first expression, $(12)$ is not in the set since the set is trivial.

Comment: @pxc3110 Yes, sorry, that bit isn't quite right. I don't have time to correct it at the moment so I'll just edit it out. I'll try and find time later. Basically, it should be "elements $g$ such that for all $x\in G$ there exists $h\in H$ with $g=x^{-1}hx$".

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
\begin{align}
y^{-1}Ny&=y^{-1}(\bigcap _{x\in G} x^{-1}Hx)y\\
&=\bigcap_{x\in G}(y^{-1}x^{-1}Hxy)\\
&=\bigcap_{x\in G}((xy)^{-1}H(xy))\\
&=\bigcap_{x\in G}(g^{-1}Hg)
\end{align}
where  $g=xy$

Thus conjugating with $y$ just rearranges the terms of  $\bigcap_{x\in G} x^{-1}Hx$. (as one to one and onto)

Thus, the result.

Comment: How to ensure that xy represents all of the elements in G? Can you show that to me?

Comment: Left multiplication by an element of the group acts as a permutation. For one-one, suppose xa=xb, then by left multiplying by the inverse of x, you get a=b. Of course, onto as x(x^-1a)=a. For every element a, you are able to find a preimage x^-1a

Answer (score 1):

Let $a, b \in N$, we need to prove that: $ab^{-1} \in N$. First we prove that $x^{-1}Hx$ is a subgroup of $G$ for any $x \in G$. For if $s, t \in x^{-1}Hx$, then $s = x^{-1}yx$, and $t = x^{-1}zx$ for some $y, z \in H$. So $st^{-1} = x^{-1}yxx^{-1}z^{-1}x = x^{-1}yz^{-1}x$. Since $y, z \in H$ and $H$ is a subgroup, we have: $yz^{-1} \in H$. So $x^{-1}yz^{-1}x \in x^{-1}Hx$. Thus: $st^{-1} \in x^{-1}Hx$, and $x^{-1}Hx$ is a subgroup of $G$. Now $a, b \in N$, so $a \in x^{-1}Hx$, and $b \in x^{-1}Hx$ for all $x \in G$. Since we just proved that $x^{-1}Hx$ is a subgroup of $G$, that means $ab^{-1} \in x^{-1}Hx$ for all $x \in G$. So $ab^{-1} \in \displaystyle \bigcap_{x \in G}x^{-1}Hx = N$, proving that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$. And for any $y \in G$, we have:
$y^{-1}Ny = \displaystyle \bigcap_{x \in G}y^{-1}x^{-1}Hxy = \displaystyle \bigcap_{x \in G}(xy)^{-1}Hxy = \displaystyle \bigcap_{z \in G}z^{-1}Hz = N$. We're done.

Comment: G could be infinite, so you also have to prove that for every element in the set there exists an inverse for it. Aside, to check the closure, you have to prove that if $s,t\in x^{-1}Hx$, then*$st\in x^{-1}Hx$*, not $st^{-1}$ according to what I've learned so far.